# Weblogic 11g URL Rewrite

Tags: oracle, weblogic, url-rewriting, weblogic11g

I have a client running a WebLogic 11g install on a Windows Server machine who wishes to implement Apache-style mod_rewrite-like functionality to translate requests for http://easyurl.com to http://super.complicated.com/with/this/junk?here=and_more. I have scoured the Internet for advice, but all I can find are other people who are asking the same question and not getting any answer. Assuming that installing 3rd-party apps is not an option, how do I implement this in WebLogic?

Edit: Now that I think about it, this question probably belongs on Server Fault. I'll move it there.

Further edit: https://serverfault.com/questions/177795/url-rewrite-in-weblogic-11g is the Server Fault link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are using Apache HTTPD with the [Apache HTTP Server Plug-In](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/plugins/apache.html) in front of WebLogic, then it should be possible to use `mod_rewrite` before to send request to WebLogic.
- If not, then you could use Tuckey's [Url Rewrite Filter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (a Java Filter) that allows to rewrite URLs in a `mod_rewrite` like manner at the application server level.

Comment: c.f. my responses on Server Fault. I'll remove this question here to reduce confusion. edit: Never mind, deletion isn't unilateral for someone of my rep.

Comment: @wilsona This question is IMO appropriate for SO as it may involve "programming" (with the Filter part). As I answered on SF, the filter is not a WebLogic add-on, this is a Servlet Filter, it's part of the web app.

Comment: A good argument, but it's still code that would have to be managed that isn't delivered with the system as-is (this particular WebLogic installation is part of a system package install), so it's not completely desirable in this particular case (management of new code requires a lot of documentation with this particular client). Since it would work almost everywhere else, though, I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out of the box with weblogic. The least invasive is to implement Pascal's suggestion of a url rewrite filter. I had the exact same requirement (implement this with just weblogic, no additional code as it would have to be managed/documented, etc) and there was no way to do this.

Comment: 10 years later I am facing the same issue. Any update on this? Maybe Weblogic evolved and it is now possible? But until now I have not seen the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either PrettyFaces or OCPsoft Rewrite for this. Both are more updated solutions to the URL-rewriting domain:

http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

http://ocpsoft.com/rewrite/