# Disable URL rewriting for specific URLs in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, weblogic

We are trying to disable url rewriting (sessionid in the url) only for specific urls to the web application. Right now the url rewriting is enabled and due to some problem we need to disable url rewriting to specific urls that the application serve.

we don't use spring framework, we use inbuilt framework in our organisation. we use weblogic server.

Is it possible? How to achieve this?

Comment: URL rewriting can happen in more places, basically in the servlet container (application server), in the framework (Spring etc.), or in the proxying HTTP server. And of course in the web application itself (e.g. using a servlet filter). The configuration of the rewriting is server / framework / application specific, so if you want someone to help you, you need to share more details about your situation (i.e. what server and/or framework you use, etc.).

Comment: How is the URL rewriting configured now?

Comment: @Jozef : URLrewriting is enabled in weblogic.xml of the webapp.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible (according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/webapp/weblogic_xml.html#1062269 - it is just an on/off switch), but I am not an Weblogic expert. (Originally, I thought you mean a [general URL rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), not just the Weblogic-specific one.)

Comment: You might need a third party filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637147/weblogic-11g-url-rewrite