# Where in application is URL queryString generated

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, query-string

The Url to my application is

```
     https://abc.xyz.portal.com
```

When I hit this URL inside the browser, the login page loads with the below URL at the top in the browser

```
  https://abc.xyz.portal.com/klp/tyu/DoUp?action=login&TYPE=43434343&REALMOID=87-3334re-444-3456-h667-87678h
```

I would like to know where in the application is this querystring is configured such that the main URL is redirected to the below querystring.
Is it the Webserver?

I have observed the same in

```
  https://www.google.com
```

where google produces the below query string

```
 https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=GFwRVsfJOZSr8wfKhImIDA&gws_rd=ssl
```

Comment: I'm afraid that yes: this is probably triggered but kind of a security context configured in weblogic. I'm not knowledgeable in weblogic, but it seems so.

Comment: To give you a proper answer we will need to know what is your web server, your web.xml configuration (or your server configuration, depending where the security context is configured) and also see the filters you have if it is the case! Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Webserver is Oracle Iplanet. Web.xml has configuration to load the servlets and filters.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons url rewriting mode is enabled in your application environment

Please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644570